# Probability: Cdf Transformation

Tags: probability

Hi guys Iam stuck on this question:
Bacteria are grown in a dish for a length of time (in hours) $T$ which is a random variable with a uniform distribution over the range $[5,6]$; that is, it has the *p.d.f*

$$f(t) = \left\{
  \begin{array}{l l}
    1 & \quad \text{for $5\leq t\leq6$}\\
    0 & \quad \text{$elsewhere$}
  \end{array} \right.$$

and $Y=e^{cT}$

Write down the cumulative distribution of $T$ and hence find the cumulative distribution function of $Y$.

answer:

> $F(t)=t$
>
> C.d.f of $Y: P(T\leq t)= t, Y=e^{cT}$, so $Pr(\frac{1}{c}\times Ln(Y)\leq t)=t$ 
>   rearrange to get, $Pr(Y\leq e^{ct})=t$, after this $i$ substituted $y=e^{ct}$, so
>   $Pr(Y\leq y)=\frac{1}{c}\times Ln(y)$.

Can some body tell me if this is the correct method and if not can you please tell me where I went wrong.

Thanks

Comment: Your method is okay, but you've miscalculated the CDF of $T$. See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

$\DeclareMathOperator{\Pr}{Pr}$You've incorrectly calculated the CDF of $T$. In particular, it is given by $$F(t):=\Pr(T\le t)=\int_{-\infty}^tf(s)\,ds,$$ so proceeding casewise, we see that $$F(t)=\begin{cases}0 & \text{if }t\le 5\\t-5 & \text{if }5<t<6\\1 & \text{if }t\ge 6.\end{cases}$$ Note then that the following are equivalent for any positive $y$: $$Y\le y\\e^{cT}\le y\\cT\le\ln(y)\\T\le\frac{\ln(y)}{c}$$ Now, since we're talking about exponential growth, then $c$ must be positive. Hence, observing that $$5<\frac{\ln(y)}{c}<6$$ if and only if $$e^{5c}<y<e^{6c},$$ the CDF of $Y$ is given by $$\Pr(Y\le y)=\begin{cases}0 & \text{if }y\le e^{5c}\\\frac{\ln(y)}{c}-5 & \text{if }e^{5c}<y<e^{6c}\\1 & \text{if }y\ge e^{6c}.\end{cases}$$